# is there any efficiant way to autoup date tkinter labels, as my program getting slower when i add more tkinter Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i am working on a trading bot creation, as a part of that i have an interface which is having more than 12 tkinter labels. And they are auto updating some values from broker (updating/sec.).There is a field called 'Last updated time'(present time, i.e datetime.datetime.now()), When i run the program with just 2 Labels, Labels are updating like one update per Second, that is Last updated time field runs like 1, 2, 3... sequence. But when i started to add more Labels i.e approximately 10 to 15, the program started to run slow. The update is now just like 1 update per 20 or 30 Seconds.Now the time field runs like 1, 20, 44.. Is there any way to do the same efficiently. right now i am coding like below.

```
def runner():
    while True:
        lab0.config(text=('Time=', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S')))
        lab1.config(text=('JPY=', db_data()['Close'].iloc[-1]))
        lab2.config(text=('JPY_High=', db_data()['High'].iloc[-1]))
        lab3.config(text=('JPY_SMA=', sma().iloc[-1]))
        lab4.config(text=('JPY_EMA=', ema().iloc[-1]))
        lab5.config(text=('JPY_rsi=', rsi().iloc[-1]))
        lab6.config(text=('JPY_atr=', atr().iloc[-1]))
        lab7.config(text=('JPY_ao=', ao().iloc[-1]))
        lab8.config(text = ('JPY_adx=', adx()['ADX_14'].iloc[-1]))
        lab9.config(text=('JPY_hi_lo=', hi_lo().iloc[-1]))
        window.update()
        time.sleep(1)
runner()
```

and i tried below given method as well.

```
def runner():
      lab0.config(text=('Time=', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S')))
      lab1.config(text=('JPY=', db_data()['Close'].iloc[-1]))
      lab2.config(text=('JPY_High=', db_data()['High'].iloc[-1]))
      lab3.config(text=('JPY_SMA=', sma().iloc[-1]))
      lab4.config(text=('JPY_EMA=', ema().iloc[-1]))
      lab5.config(text=('JPY_rsi=', rsi().iloc[-1]))
      lab6.config(text=('JPY_atr=', atr().iloc[-1]))
      lab7.config(text=('JPY_ao=', ao().iloc[-1]))
      lab8.config(text = ('JPY_adx=', adx()['ADX_14'].iloc[-1]))
      lab9.config(text=('JPY_hi_lo=', hi_lo().iloc[-1]))
    
      lab0.after(1000, runner)
runner()
```

Both are giving same result, that is when i add more Labels the code is getting slower. Anyone please help. i am using both MacOS and Linux same problem is experiencing on both OS.

i am expecting what are the methods that professionals use to create tkinter interface, when we are handling with more auto updating Labels

Comment: You should avoid using `sleep()` anywhere in a tkinter application, as your GUI will hang as long as `sleep()` is happening. You're on the right track using `after()`. Generally, you should use `root.after(1000, runner)` where `root` here should be the name of your instance of `Tk()`

Comment: is it better to use root.after(1000, runner) than lab0.after(1000, runner) i.e to use Tk() instead of Label?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, using `root` schedules the function call in the `root` event loop - but someone please correct me if this is off-base!

Comment: `after` does exactly the same thing no matter which widget you call it on.

Comment: The slowness probably isn't caused by tkinter. Each update calls multiple functions, and I bet those functions are relatively slow. The solution is probably to figure out how to make fewer function calls, or make the function calls run faster.

Comment: yes, which uses multiple functions and those functions again use another functions inside of them. That may be a cause. But when i am using without graphics that is these values are displaying and updating in console, there is no more slowness.